# How do I change the color of turrets on the mini-map?

Tags: league-of-legends

I can't figure out how to make the turrets look blue/red on the mini-map like some of the streams have. Can anyone help?

Comment: Blue/Orange colors means the game is being played in Colorblind mode.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to change map colors that I know of is:

*Options → Video → Enable Colorblind Mode*

Answer (score 2):

You click <kbd>Esc</kbd> then options then video and you enable the colorblind mode